# How to get the asm acm kf versions of gcp kubernetes cluster using python script

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, connection, cloud

How to get asm,acm,kf version of a gcp gke cluster using python inbuilt function of gcp

I tried gcloud commands in python code that don't looks good

Its not a effective solution to do in that way instead we can use python fun which stick stable